# @RequestBody that accepts both List and Single object

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest

I have this code for a RestAPI (simplified for the purpose of this question).

```
public class UserRequestDTO {
    
    private Long userId;
    
    private List<Email> email;

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public List<Email> getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(List<Email> email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}


@RestController
public class UserController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/user", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<UserResponseDTO> addUser(@RequestBody UserRequestDTO userRequestDTO) {

        ....
    }

}
```

The above code sucessfully creates userRequestDTO for the following POST request body (Postman) that has several emails:

```
{
    "email": [
      {
      "type": "primary",
      "value": "contact1@gmail.com"
      },
      {
      "type": "primary",
      "value": "contact2@gmail.com"
      }
    ] 
}
```

But it does not create userRequestDTO for this other POST request body that has just one email:

```
{
  "email": {
    "type": "primary",
    "value": "contact1@gmail.com"
   } 
}
```

The thing is that I have a requirement to make both type of requests (one and several emails) work.

I cannot edit the json postman request. That's how it comes. I need the change to be in the Java code.

How to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to configure deserialization in Jackson. For example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {
   @Bean
   @Primary
   public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
      return new ObjectMapper().enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
   }
}
```

Comment: It's a SpringBoot application. I don't have a class annoted with '@Configuration'. I have one annotated with '@SpringBootApplication'. Should I add this code in this one? Just adding that code should be enough or there's code to change in the '@RestController' class as well?

Comment: It's very simple... @SpringBootApplication scans components in the same package as the main class of your application and in child packages. Place AppConfiguration next to the class annotated by AppConfiguration. Or create this bean using XML configuration.

Comment: I placed the class you proposed in the same package of the @SpringBootApplication class and it worked. Thank you. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 4):

For the benefit of others, I found another solution that is even simpler than the solution proposed by @Alexander Kashpirovsky that I checked as the accepted one.

```
public class UserRequestDTO {   
    ... 
    @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
    private List<Email> email;
    ...
}
```

Comment: This good way, but for single field or entity.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit odd requirements to be fair but is not impossible this is what I could think of a custom Deserializer , thanks to Jackson is really easy to implement , the main idea behind this realization is that inside your code email will always be an array , but it will be assembled differently base on incoming JSON , this is mine POJO

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonDeserialize(using = AgentSerializer.class)
public class Agent {

    private Long id;

    private List<String> name;
}
```

and based on this I have a custom deserializer

```
package com.mihai.learn.domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JacksonException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class AgentSerializer extends JsonDeserializer<Agent> {

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public Agent deserialize(final JsonParser jsonParser,
                             final DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JacksonException {


        final TreeNode treeNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        final Long id = Long.parseLong(treeNode.get("id").toString());
        final TreeNode name = treeNode.get("name");

        boolean areMultipleName = name.isArray();

        final List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

        if (areMultipleName) {
            final List<String> strings = mapper.readValue(name.toString(), new TypeReference<>() {
            });
            names.addAll(strings);
        } else {
            final String s = mapper.readValue(name.toString(), String.class);
            names.add(s);
        }

        return new Agent(id, names);
    }
}
```

I checked it works with both type of request

```
{
    "id": 100,
    "name": "name"
}
```

and

```
{
    "id":100,
    "name":[
        "name",
        "name2"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I could solve it with the solution proposed by @Alexander Kashpirovsky which is simpler.